# Updating the block_timestamp after each function call

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to update the block_timestamp after each function call.
This is how I am updating the context after each function call in tests.

```
#[test]
    fn set_then_get_greeting() {
        let context = get_context(vec![], false);
        testing_env!(context);
        let mut contract = Welcome::new();
        contract.set_record("7dd".to_owned());
        let context = get_context(vec![], false);
        testing_env!(context);
        contract.update_record("7dd".to_owned());
        
    }
```

But on state update it gives follow error:

```
panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InconsistentStateError(IntegerOverflow)'
```

How can I update the block_timestamp with every function call?

Code: https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTNHuRryBoDmTp7wqmNsCcJW8Gu7G6dz3cE3F4pynv6V9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was because `storage_usage` was set to zero. Setting it to large number solves it.

https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/issues/216

Comment: Thanks for following up on this - same problem and same solution. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what `get_context` is doing, but you can modify context before calling `testing_env!` and then pass a cloned copy.

For example:

```
#[test]
    fn set_then_get_greeting() {
        let mut context = get_context(vec![], false);
        testing_env!(context.clone());

        let mut contract = Welcome::new();
        contract.set_record("7dd".to_owned());

        context.block_timestamp += 1000;
        testing_env!(context.clone());

        contract.update_record("7dd".to_owned());
    }
```

The error you see might be unrelated to the `context` because it complains about inconsistent state, which likely means something is off with the persistent collections.

Comment: No, it still gives error. Please see the attached code.